# content.js not receiving message from popup.js

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

### Summarize the problem

I am making a Chrome extension where I need to send messages between `popup.js` and `content.js`.

### Describe what you've tried

I tried running the code below which just resulted in nothing happening, which of course is not correct. I've been scouring the web for answers and I came across the Message Passing article from Chrome. I followed their exact guidelines but still no result. Has something changed, a new update that I just can't find?

I also get this error in the console when I click the `Apply Search` button.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Error in invocation of tabs.query(object queryInfo, function callback): No matching signature.
    at HTMLButtonElement.applySearches (popup.js:24:29)
```

### Files

[image]

### Show some code

#### popup.js

```
let searches = [];

function addSearch() {
  const search = document.getElementById("searchTerm").value;
  const color = document.getElementById("colorPicker").value;

  if (!searches.find((entry) => entry.search === search))
    searches.push({ search, color });

  updateSearches();
}

function updateSearches() {
  const searchesList = document.getElementById("searchList");
  searchesList.innerHTML = "";
  for (const search of searches) {
    const li = document.createElement("li");
    li.textContent = `${search.search}, ${search.color}`;
    searchesList.appendChild(li);
  }
}

async function applySearches() {
  const [tab] = await chrome.tabs.query({
    active: true,
    lastFocusedWindow: true,
  });
  await chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {
    action: "applySeraches",
    searches,
  });
}

document.getElementById("addSearchButton").addEventListener("click", addSearch);
document
  .getElementById("applySearchesButton")
  .addEventListener("click", applySearches);
```

#### content.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
  console.log(
    sender.tab
      ? "from a content script:" + sender.tab.url
      : "from the extension"
  );
});
```

#### popup.html

```
<!-- popup.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="popup.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app">
      <h2>MultiSearch PDF</h2>
      <div>
        <label for="searchTerm">Search Term:</label>
        <input type="text" id="searchTerm" />
        <label for="colorPicker">Select Color:</label>
        <input type="color" id="colorPicker" />
        <button id="addSearchButton">Add Search</button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h3>Search List:</h3>
        <div id="searchList"></div>
      </div>
      <button id="applySearchesButton">Apply Searches</button>
      <div id="debugWindow">
        <h2>Debug Window</h2>
        <div id="debugWindowContent"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: 1) This code can't cause such error, so you probably look at an old error from the past attempts. Click the `Clear all` button or the trashcan icon to remove it. Note that the popup is a separate window so it has its own separate devtools: right-click inside the popup and select "inspect" in the menu. 2) You need to [re-inject content scripts](/q/10994324) after reloading/installing the extension.

Comment: 1. Yes I realised that, thanks.
2. I am refreshing the page between updates, etc. But I still have the same issue.

Comment: I have now made the changes that the other post suggested, and updated my manifest to v3. Though now I get a 
TypeError: chrome.runtime.getManifest.content_scripts is not iterable
    at background.js:2:48

Comment: It's getManifest() with (). Try using currentWindow instead of lastFocusedWindow. Also make sure that you don't have an undocked devtools window focused when you open the popup.